# Drools dslr - passing a list

Tags: list, drools, rules

In a dslr, can you pass a list of values to a condition or Drools is limited to one single value?

I would like to write something like:

```
[condition][]The customer firstName is in this list {nameList}=...
```

instead of

```
[condition][]The customer firstName is {name1} or {name2} or {name3}=...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DRL construct that fits is the compound restriction using "in", written as e.g.

```
Person( name in ("Joe", "Tom", "Fred") )
```

In your case the DSLR definition should be

```
[condition][]The customer firstName is in this list {nameList}=
    Customer( firstName in ({nameList}) )
```

Note that in the DSL you'll have to write the names in quotes:

```
The customer firstName is in this list "Joe","Tom","Fred"
```

Comment: thank you laune, this is what I was looking for. Is there a way also to access the list in the right hand bit of the DSLR? Something like:
`[condition][]These 3 customers {customerList} have at least this age: {ageList}={customerList}[0].age == {ageList}[0] , ...`

Comment: This will not result in valid DRL code, and I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Perhaps you close this Q+A and start a new one with more background?